# Selecting one specific class in an unordered list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm new to HTML/CSS and i'm trying to select one specific class for styling in an unordered list.

I want to be able to select the HTML code: `<li class="nav-header"><a href="#">WOMEN'S WEAR</a></li>` in CSS.

I have tried to select the code by using `.dropdown-header:nth-child(2)` for making changes on the `width` from `110px` to `150px`, but nothing happens.

` 
Here's the full code:

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-header"><a href="#">MEN'S WEAR</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-background">
            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">TOPWEAR</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a class="browse" href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">BOTTOMWEAR</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Colour Jeans</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Pants</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Shorts</a></li>   
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">FOOTWEAR</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Boots</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Sandals</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Snickers</a></li>         
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Belts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Caps</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Hats</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Scarves</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Gloves</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Sunglasses</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Watches</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Jewelry</a></li>              
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">SALE</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li class="nav-header"><a href="#">WOMEN'S WEAR</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-background">
            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">TOPWEAR</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a class="browse" href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">BOTTOMWEAR</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Colour Jeans</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Pants</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Shorts</a></li>   
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">FOOTWEAR</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Boots</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Sandals</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Snickers</a></li>         
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Belts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Caps</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Hats</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Scarves</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Gloves</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Sunglasses</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Watches</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Jewelry</a></li>              
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">SALE</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Jackets & Coats</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Overshirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Basic T-Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Knitwear</a></li>
                <li><a class="browse"  href="#">Sweats</a></li>            
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* ------------------ NAVIGATION BAR ------------------ */
    .navigation {


      position: relative;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        width: 1024px;
        height: 42px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;

      -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    }

    .navigation a {
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
          -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
           -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
            -o-transition: all .25s ease;
               transition: all .25s ease;
    }

    .nav-header:nth-child(1) { 
      width: 110px;
      height: 30px;
      float: left;
      padding-top: 13px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
          -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
           -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
            -o-transition: all .25s ease;
               transition: all .25s ease;
     }


    .nav-header:hover {
      background: #000;
    }


    .nav-header ul {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      visibility: hidden;
      top: 14px;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
         -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
          -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
           -o-transition: all .25s ease;
              transition: all .25s ease;  
    }

    .nav-header:hover ul {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .nav-header a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000;
    }

    .nav-header:hover  a{
      color: #fff;

    }

    .dropdown-background {
      background: #000;
      width: 1024px;
      height: 265px;
      right: 10px;
    }

    .dropdown-header {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      top: 10px;

    }

    .dropdown-header a {
      padding-right: 60px;
      color: #fff;
      padding-left: 10px;

    }

    .dropdown-header a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .browse {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 25px;
    }

    .browse:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Comment: You don't want to give it an id?

Comment: sure, would that be better?

Comment: hmmm, I am actually newish to HTML/CSS as well, but if it were me, based on what I know, I would give it an ID. However, I have been told its best to avoid using ID when possible as it makes for larger CSS style sheets. In other words, try to stay as general as possible. But if you don't mind, giving it an ID seems like it would work fine to me

Comment: ID's and classes are always good to use. I would give the main categories of that menu a specific class like "head-menu" or something and target those directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets apply this pseudo element style.

```
nav ul:nth-of-type(2) > li.nav-header
{

  width:150px;
}
```

this will do the trick. Here is a Working Demo. http://jsbin.com/suxumefe/1/

Comment: Thanks alot! What if I wanted to select the class `dropdown-background` in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<!--in html code add id-->
<li class="nav-header" id="womans-wear"><a href="#">WOMEN'S WEAR</a>
<!--end html-->
```

CSS

```
#womans-wear{

    /*add your styles in here*/
    width:150px;

}
```

Something like this, per the explanation above in the comments

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
.navigation ul:nth-of-type(2) > .nav-header a {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Though it should be noted, if you **can** add a class to the second ul that you are targeting, add it so that your style will work on browsers that [do not support nth-of-type](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3). Also, using an ID instead of a class is not preferred by [many CSS authorities](http://css-tricks.com/css-style-guides/) due to creating selectors that are too specific and difficult to override.